# using Join on List View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join, lambda

I just wanted to display a list using join. I was wondering if
a. If there was a better way of doing this?
b. How to convert the join linq query to lambda expression?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ctx = new BarCodeContext();

        var query = (from i in ctx.Import
                     join p in ctx.Piece
                         on i.PieceNo equals p.PieceNo
                     select new { i.Ref, i.Customer, i.JobNo, i.ItemNo }).ToList();

        List<ListPiece> list = new List<ListPiece>();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            list.Add(new ListPiece
            {
                Ref = item.Ref,
                Customer = item.Customer,
                JobNo = item.JobNo,
                ItemNo = item.ItemNo,
            });
        }

        return View(list);
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var ctx = new BarCodeContext();
  List<ListPiece> list = ctx.Import.Join(ctx.Piece,
      i => i.PieceNo,
      p => p.PieceNo,
      (i, p) => new ListPiece {
          Ref = i.Ref,
          Customer = i.Customer,
          JobNo = i.JobNo,
          ItemNo = i.ItemNo
      }).ToList();
  return View(list);
}
```

Comment: Yep. It works perfect. Lambda expression is not that bad once you get a hang of it. Thank you